# How to Host a .net application in AWS S3

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to host a .net application on AWS S3 using static website hosting, is there any possibility to do so? Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, .net is used to dynamically generate pages. It's the opposite of a static website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can front your UI artifacts in S3, but the .Net part will have to be executed server side by a Web Server like `IIS`. S3 just serves files: doesn't execute them, so you'll need more than S3 to pull this off.

There are various AWS services you can look at to help you get started on hosting .Net solutions including EC2, ECS (.Net core) and Lambda (.Net runtime).

Comment: Thanks alot peter for your explanation.